# Mouse not working with Monogame in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, monogame

I've embedded Monogame into a Windows Form using this code:

```
    private IntPtr drawSurface;
    private Control gameForm;

    public MapEditor(MainWindow window)
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        this.drawSurface = window.pcbViewport.Handle;
        graphics.PreparingDeviceSettings += new EventHandler<PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs>(graphics_PreparingDeviceSettings);
        Mouse.WindowHandle = drawSurface;
        gameForm = Control.FromHandle(this.Window.Handle);
        gameForm.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(gameForm_VisibleChanged);
    }  

    private void gameForm_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gameForm.Visible)
        {
            gameForm.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void graphics_PreparingDeviceSettings(object sender, PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs e)
    {
        e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.DeviceWindowHandle = drawSurface;
    }
```

Now, this code used to work... I think. It's been a while and the code is on another computer with an older version so I seem to remember this working before now with Monogame. Anyway, the problem is that Mouse input doesn't work! Keyboard and Gamepad input work fine, but Mouse input doesn't register at all. I've experimented and found that if I take out the VisibleChanged event, it works but it also shows the GameWindow as well as the form (which it doesn't need to as it's being drawn in the PictureBox.

I'm aware that I can put the GameWindow in a Control, and if need be then I'll do that but I'm trying to see if there is a solution to making the existing code work again.

Comment: Why do you need to set it to invisible? Mouse input is directed to the window below the mouse (in typical situations), but if it's not visible it can't receive that mouse input.

Comment: How and where are you creating the Game instance/Form instance? As @MicroVirus wrote, hiding a WinForms `Control` will prevent it from receiving mouse input. Also, I am presuming `MapEditor` is derived from `Game`?

Comment: It's invisible because it renders to a picturebox inside the winform. If it's visible then you have two windows, the GameWindow and the one in the Winform! Which is kind of the problem if you can't reassign the Mouse control. The Game Instance is created alongside the Winform and assigned to the Winform.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your approach is that setting `Mouse.WindowHandle` in `MonoGame` does nothing (the setter for this property is empty, if you [look at the source code](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Input/Mouse.cs#L116)).<sup>1</sup>

This means that your `Game` is always bound to its default window (the one that you are hiding), and that all mouse input outside that window is ignored. If you don't hide it, you will see that clicking into the original window creates mouse events correctly. Draws, on the other hand, are done to the picture box correctly. Keyboard events are not filtered by screen area, so they work without issues.

My opinion is that this is not how you should be hosting XNA/MonoGame inside Windows Forms, but instead look into how to implement a `GraphicsDeviceControl` class, which should inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` and provide the ability to draw itself by using an XNA Framework `GraphicsDevice`. The approach is explained in [this article](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1) (XNA 4, but can be easily ported to MonoGame).

If you do want to use the approach you are using right now, the only thing you *can* do is checkout MonoGame source code, and find the implementation of `GameWindow` for windows forms (that is, `WinFormsGameWindow`, which is an internal class). Since `Mouse.GetState()` merely returns `GameWindow.MouseState`, a possibility to instantiate your own `GameWindow` would allow you to get the events filtered by *your* window.

Or, if you are changing MonoGame code anyway, then you might as well add a `Game` constructor overload which would accept the `Control` handle from the start.

---

<sup>1</sup> Ironically, there is a comment inside that this setter was left "only for XNA compatibility", like throwing a compile-time error is a big deal compared to the time people will lose debugging this. :-D

Comment: Well darn, I was hoping for an easy fix but I knew the transition from XNA to Monogame was bound to have some problems! Thank you for the concise answer and the suggestions. The first option was actually my alternative, the other two options are viable as well but I'd rather let Monogame be monogame and my code do things in a more "proper" fashion. Can't believe though they left in dead code without so much as a comment or exception... darn programmers!