# Monogame (Linux) - MouseState.ScrollWheelValue not changing

Tags: monogame

I have a monogame project created in visual studio with MonoGame 3.5. After running it on linux, `mouseState.ScrollWheelValue` is always 0, regardless of anything I do.

This most likely has to do something with the fact that linux has different window focus regarding mouse wheel, but I can't seem to figure it out.

**What I found so far:**

**1.** I should set `Mouse.WindowHandle` to correct value (*whatever that means*).
This is largely problematic, since Mouse.WindowHandle setter is not implemented. Plus injecting a specific window into the Mouse object is an internal procedure. (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33921015/3455388 )

**2.** A poor soul that asked this question on official monogame forums 3 years ago, with no visible answer (https://community.monogame.net/t/mouse-state-scrollwheelvalue-returns-0-all-the-time/9233)

Does anyone know how to make MonoGame receive MouseWheel events on linux? An answer that this is simply not supported is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but resolving a different problem related to sound resolved the mouse issue as well.

When initially running my game on linux, I got a second issue with sound library: `Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: openal32.dll`. I simply disabled sounds and dug in the MouseWheel issue.

After giving up on the mouse issue, I returned back to fix the sounds, and found a guy talking about missing files in the `/bin/Windows/Debug/` folder (https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/657).

Turns out my MonoGame bin directory only contained `OpenTK.dll`, but was missing `OpenTK.dll.config`. Copying it from `/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/MonoGame/v3.0/Tools/` resolved the sounds... **and** the mouse. I *guess* the missing library might have crashed the initialization process before the mouse was correctly set up..